# How to drag an image from Qtablewidget and add it to the scene?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QTablewidget containing images in its cell .my goal is to drag the image from tablewidget and drop it in the scene.

I have tried to implement dragevents inside Qtablewidgets but it is not working.I have given a sample code.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QByteArray,QDataStream, QIODevice,pyqtSlot, QMimeData, QPointF, QPoint, Qt, QRect,QTimer,QLineF, QEvent,QRectF)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor,QDrag, QPainter, QPixmap,QFont,QFontMetrics,QBrush, QLinearGradient, QIcon, QPen, QPainterPath, QTransform,QCursor,QMouseEvent,QClipboard
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QGraphicsTextItem,QGraphicsItemGroup, QSizePolicy,QShortcut, QScrollArea, QPushButton,QLineEdit, QMainWindow,QInputDialog, QGraphicsPathItem,QDialog, QVBoxLayout,QGraphicsItem,QStatusBar,QTextEdit, QAction,QMenu, qApp,QSplitter, QButtonGroup, QToolButton, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QLabel, QGraphicsScene, QWidget
import table1 as table


class GraphicsSceneClass(QGraphicsScene):
    global selectedObjType
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsSceneClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gridOn = 0
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))




class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    global selectedObjType
    # global item
    def __init__(self,):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # self.createActions()
        # self.createMenus()
        # self.createToolbars()

        self.scene = GraphicsSceneClass()
        MainWindow.obj = self.scene
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        # self.view.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.view.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
        self.widg = QWidget()
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.table=QWidget()
        self.table.setLayout( table.Drag1Window())
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.view)


        self.widg.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another module-table1.py

```
class Drag1Window(QVBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Drag1Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSpacing(0)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setGeometry(QRect(0,0,0,0))
        self.layoutdimension = DragTableItem()
        self.layoutdimension.setMinimumSize(300,300)
        self.addWidget(self.layoutdimension)






class DragTableItem(QTableWidget):

    global selectedObjType
    global rows
    rows = []
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragTableItem, self).__init__()
        self.setRowCount(20)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        # self.MyTable = QTableWidget(2,2)
        # filename = "SIG.csv"
        self.dragEnabled()
        col = "FlipHor"
        newItem = QTableWidgetItem(col)

        self.setImage(0, 1, "symbol.png")

                # Track_Image = QLabel(self)
                # pixmap = QPixmap('Track.png')
                # Track_Image.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def setImage(self, row, col, imagePath):
        image = ImageWidget(imagePath, self)
        self.setCellWidget(row, col, image)

class ImageWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, imagePath, parent):
        super(ImageWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.picture = QPixmap(imagePath)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter1 = QPainter(self)
        painter1.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.picture)
```

can anyone help me to drag the image in the cell and drop it in the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a widget to support drag you must override the mousePressEvent() method.

```py
class ImageWidget(QWidget):
    # ...

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mimeData = QMimeData()
            mimeData.setImageData(self.picture)
            drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
            drag.setPixmap(self.picture)
            drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
            drag.exec_()
```

And to support the drop you must override the dragEnterEvent(), dragMoveEvent() and dropEvent() methods, in addition to enabling the acceptDrops flag.

```py
class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        # ...
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)


    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage():
            pixmap = event.mimeData().imageData()
            if self.scene() is not None:
                it = self.scene().addPixmap(pixmap)
                it.setPos(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            event.acceptProposedAction()
```

Complete example:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QDrag, QPainter, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 640, 480)
        self.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(GraphicsScene(self))
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage():
            pixmap = event.mimeData().imageData()
            if self.scene() is not None:
                it = self.scene().addPixmap(pixmap)
                it.setPos(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            event.acceptProposedAction()


class ImageWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, imagePath, parent=None):
        super(ImageWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.picture = QPixmap(imagePath)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter1 = QPainter(self)
        painter1.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.picture)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mimeData = QMimeData()
            mimeData.setImageData(self.picture)
            drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
            drag.setPixmap(self.picture)
            drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
            drag.exec_()


class DragTableItem(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragTableItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setRowCount(20)
        self.setColumnCount(2)

        col = "FlipHor"
        newItem = QTableWidgetItem(col)
        self.setImage(0, 1, "symbol.png")

    def setImage(self, row, col, imagePath):
        image = ImageWidget(imagePath)
        self.setCellWidget(row, col, image)


class DragWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.tableitem = DragTableItem()
        self.tableitem.setMinimumSize(300,300)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableitem)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.view = GraphicsView()
        self.table = DragWindow()

        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A complete guide to drag-and-drop on Qt is [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html)

Comment: I have one more problem with the above code.I am not able to select the row in which the image has added.It is not passing cell clicked signal